# Is there any way to do this, assign a value within a List<T>.ForEach() statement?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have this:

```
var lineArray = line.Split(';');

lineArray.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    if (x == "(null)")
        x = "NULL";
    else
        x = string.Format("'{0}'", x);
});
```

This runs fine, but does not seem to change the elements within `lineArray`. I thought of assigning the results of `ForEach` to a `var` but it returns void.

Any ideas ?

EDIT: I think it's because `ToList()` return value is not assigned anywhere...

Comment: don't use `ForEach` like that - use a `for` loop.

Comment: @Steve I would not go so far as to say `rare`. There are many cases where each one has particular merit.

Comment: Merely reassigning to `x` isn't going to change the source sequence no matter how you go about it. You would need to write the new `x` back to the list or array. The answers below, of course, show you various techniques to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var lineArray = line.Split(';')
                    .Select(x=>x == "(null)"
                               ? "NULL"
                               : string.Format("'{0}'", x))
                    .ToArray();
```

you are trying to use `List<T>.ForEach(Action<T> action)` with lambda expression (T is string here)

if lambda expression is replaced with named method it turns out that only method argument is modified, but changes are not reflected on calling side, because `x` is not `ref` argument

```
private void Replace(string x)
{
    if (x == "(null)")
        x = "NULL";
    else
        x = string.Format("'{0}'", x);
}

var list = lineArray.ToList();
list.ForEach(Replace);
// check list here and make sure that there are no changes
```

ForEach could work if T is a reference type and action modifies some properties but not the reference itself

Comment: Is that second example supposed to work? Because it cannot work. What are you trying to show there?

Comment: @poke, the 2nd example is translation of question code without lambda. lambda adds a bit of complexity and example with a named method (which doesn't modify list, of course) shows how it actually works

Comment: Oh, I see. That wasn’t really that clear from the way you wrote it.

Answer (score 5):

don't use `ForEach` like that - use a `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lineArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (lineArray[i] == "(null)")
        lineArray[i] = "NULL";
    else
        lineArray[i] = string.Format("'{0}'", lineArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can construct a new list from your original one :

```
var newList = lineArray.Select(x => x == "(null)" ? "NULL" : string.Format("'{0}'", x));
```

Comment: At the cost of memory, which may or may not matter.

Answer (score -1):

I think this small change will work

```
 var lineArray = line.Split(';').ToList();

        lineArray.ForEach(x =>
        {
            if (x == "(null)")
                x = "NULL";
            else
                x = string.Format("'{0}'", x);
        });
```

Below is a working example

```
string line = "a;b;null;c;";

var lineArray = line.Split(';').ToList();

    lineArray.ForEach(x =>
    {
        if (x == "(null)")
            x = "NULL";
        else
            x = string.Format("'{0}'", x);
    });
```

Result:[image]

If you need just to remove (null) values from the list, you do not need to loop
just use removeAll

```
    lineArray.RemoveAll(a=>a.Equals("(null)"));
```

working example below

[image]

Comment: Your "working example" demonstrates your solution *not working.* Hint: see the null. Reassigning to *x* does not impact the element in the source sequence.

Comment: So you are trying to remove element? not just change value?

Comment: Your solution is not going to change the value in the source sequence. You are overwriting the input parameter variable x, that *doesn't* change the source.